spring annotation to get rid of configuration name prefix without changing variable names
I have configuration with
a-configuration-group
  prop1: some-hyphen-val1
  prop2: some-hyphen-val2
  .
  .
  propn: some-hyphen-valn

There are various classes using the configuration so:
SomeClass {
  @Value("${a-configuration-group.some-hyphen-val1}")
  private String someHyphenVal1;

  @Value("${a-configuration-group.some-hyphen-val2}")
  private String someHyphenVal2;
}

I would like to:

get rid of the recurring a-configuration-group.
Not change the java variable names to non-standard naming e.g. String some-hyphen-val1;
Not change the configuration property names since they are already used across the code in classes such as SomeClass AND in other configuration files which override mine. These changes will require heavy unit testing across various projects and environments.

I know about the @ConfigurationProperties as suggested here but it will conflict with 2 or 3 above.
Is there a way to add an annotation like @ConfigurationProperties but e.g. keep the @Value annotation in SomeClass as to not change variable names?

2 is a non issue as some-hyphen-val1 is the same as someHyphenVal1 when using Spring Boot configuration (I suggest the documentation instead of making wrong assumptions). 3 is a non issue as well assuming you are using proper encapsulation, provide additional getters for the old property names and everything still works as before. Mark those deprecated just as the old properties and later remove them.

Turns out spring knows how to take care of this issue using relaxed binding
Configuration remains hyphened, and code not. Spring knows to resolve.
